# How to have IQueryable marshal into single JSON object rather than array

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a controller like below that creates and returns an IQueryable from a singleton list:

```
[Route("")]    
public IQueryable<MyObject> Get() 
{
    var list = new List<MyObject> { new MyObject() };
    return list.AsQueryable();
}
```

How can I make it so that the JSON serialization of this has my object on the top level rather than an array?

Comment: Why are you returning an `IQueryable` at all?

Comment: You should return `MyObject` instead of `IQueryable<MyObject>`

Comment: I have nested objects I want to be able to run OData queries on. I was assuming I needed IQueryable for that